# Mutating fun call swift syntax

Tags: swift, syntax, mutating-function

I'm reading through the Swift 2.2 man and trying to understand a function in the mutating fun section here is the code

```
struct TestPoint {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0

    mutating func moveByX(deltaX: Double, y deltaY: Double) {
        self = TestPoint(x: x + deltaX, y: y + deltaY)
    }
}

var somePoint = TestPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
somePoint.moveByX(2.0, y: 3.0)

print("The point is now at (\(somePoint.x), \(somePoint.y))")
```

The part I'm having trouble is with the func moveByX syntax. y deltaY for example how is this allowed? y is the declared variable in the struct but where does the deltaY bit come in ?

Only two values are passed in somePoint.moveBy

Is the value passed to both y and deltaY ?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Internal and external parameter names

Let's look at the function signature of `moveByX(...)`:

```
mutating func moveByX(deltaX: Double, y deltaY: Double) 
    /*                  |            /  ^^^^^^- internal name      
                        |      external name
            internal name                                     */
```

In Swift 2.2, by default the first function parameter as no external name (`_`), which means that the function `moveByX(...)` is called as:

```
someTestPointInstance.moveByX(someXvalue, y: someYvalue)
    /*                        |           \
                no external name         external name        */
```

This means that the `y` that you see in the signature of `moveByX(...)` is just an *external parameter name*, one that no longer has any use when we've entered the body of the function (where the *internal parameter name*, `deltaY` is used). So the second argument passed to `moveByX(...)`, to the external parameter name `y`, will be referred (in this case, copied to) `deltaY` in the actual function body.

Finally note that the `x` and `y` properties used in the body of the function

```
self = TestPoint(x: x + deltaX, y: y + deltaY)
```

are the member properties `x` and `y` as defined in the definition of the `SomePoint` struct.

#### Is the above still valid for Swift 3.0?

As somewhat covered above: if we don't supply explicit external parameter names for function parameters in **Swift 2.2**, then the following rules apply:

- By default, the first function parameter will have no external parameter name (as seen above, `_`).
- By default, all the following function parameters (second, third, and so on) will have the same external parameter name as internal parameter name. So in case we would've written the function signature of `moveByX(...)` as

  ```
    mutating func moveByX(deltaX: Double, deltaY: Double)
  ```

  then the external parameter name of the second parameter would've been `deltaY`, and we would've called the function as

  ```
    someTestPointInstance.moveByX(someXvalue, deltaY: someYvalue)
  ```

In **Swift 3.0** all parameter names follows the second rule above, namely; if no external parameter name has been supplied, then the internal parameter name will be used as external parameter name for all parameters.

That means the example above would have to be modified into something along the lines

```
struct TestPoint {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0

    mutating func moveBy(x deltaX: Double, y deltaY: Double) {
        self = TestPoint(x: x + deltaX, y: y + deltaY)
    }
}

// called as 
someTestPointInstance.moveBy(x: someXvalue, y: someYvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the chapter "Function Parameter Names".

Basically, in moveByX, "y" is an external parameter name for "deltaY" and it's used to label "deltaY".

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I get it now :)